# Clicking notification from lock screen shows app with blank message drawer

Tags: bug, android-app

When I click the notification from the phone's lock screen, it opens the app but the inbox drawer is a blank dark blue. I have to close it, then click the red icon for messages and then it's populated with my inbox messages.

Using: Nexus 5, lollipop 5.1.1

Comment: You can also pull up the inbox to reload it. (as a workaround)

Comment: @Shadow_Wizard but it's still a bug

Comment: Sure, but bugs might take long time until they are fixed (sometimes years) so until then, suggesting a workaround which is faster than what you do now. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard but I'm doing exactly what you suggested. Closing the drawer and clicking the red icon.

Comment: @AndrewT. - How can an earlier question be a duplicate of a later one?

Comment: @DeerHunter if it's the same exact issue, we don't based duplicate on time, but more on the usefulness. I chose to flag this as a dupe instead, since the target dupe has screenshot, is more general (this happens not only from lock screen), and at least mention the app version.