# Clicking on a notification on Android app opens an empty feed

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, notifications

When I receive a message on an SE post, I get a notification like this:

[image: App Notification]

If I double tap this notification, the SE application opens, but my feed is empty approximately half the time. It looks like this:

[image: Empty Feed]

If I refresh the feed (slide from the top), the feed does refresh and shows the new notification.

The notification, above, leads to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262205/clicking-a-careers-link-in-android-app-redirects-to-main-careers-site?noredirect=1#comment856927_262205) comment.

I haven't figured out the pattern yet, but this occurs roughly half the time I open a notification. It's occurred for chat messages, comments and answers - but not consistently. I have received notifications for the same post (for example, the two comments after the one linked above) that do not show an empty feed. But, a chat message barely 10 minutes later will show the empty feed again.

I am utilizing the beta app - version 1.0.72 on Android 5.0.1.

Comment: Repro'd on Nexus 5, Android 5.1.1, and IIRC since 1.0.69 or 1.0.70 (also on beta).

Comment: Repro'd on Samsung S4, Android 5.0.1 on 1.0.71, but also sporadically on earlier versions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clicking notification from lock screen shows app with blank message drawer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262300/clicking-notification-from-lock-screen-shows-app-with-blank-message-drawer)

Comment: Repro'd on OnePlus One, android 5.1.1 and 5.0.1, cyanogen 12.1

Comment: reproducible on android 4.4.4 with app version 1.0.73. I wonder why this issue is still not fixed even though it was reported in version 1.0.70

Comment: @dreamweiver some bugs take long years until  a dev even see them, this one is probably not different.

Comment: As a developer I personally feel this is not a big issue .if someone hire me into SO , I can look into it ;)

Comment: This is annoying... looking into it, it's not something I've been able to see using the app internally yet.

Comment: Repro'd on Samsung S3, Android 4.4.2 with version 1.0.73 and all prior versions since I installed the app a few months ago. Happens 100% of the time on current version for me.

Comment: @Kasra any update when the fix will be pushed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sorry about the long delay, this is finally fixed.

I had to go *deep* into the rabbit hole before I found a simple fix, basically what was happening is that our notifications have a flag that tells the app if it should force a reload of the inbox or not when being viewed, this entered a weird edge case when the app was doing a cold boot so it didn't have any previous notifications cached, so it tried to jam the new one into that list instead of refreshing the entire list but since it was an empty list... well you saw what happens.

This is going to be fixed in version 1.0.74+, coming out in the next 48 hours (as soon as I figure out why my builds don't build anymore)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I DID IT

Comment: Now it's even worse - it does not go to the inbox at all, just to the last open page. :/

Comment: Update: it happens only if the app was running in background. If I remove it from memory (e.g. Clear All in LG) then tap a notification, it's working fine.

Comment: @ShadowWizard have you been able to repro this? I haven't :(

Comment: Yes happened just now with this very notification. I suspect it happens only when I have a single notification, when there are more than one it works.

Comment: @ShadowWizard what device and OS version are you using? Every time I leave the app running in the background and enter from a single push notification the inbox opens for me.

Comment: LG G3, android 5.0