# Notification glitch while on the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, notifications

*Note: I'm using the most up to date release of the app: **1.0.77** (currently)*

I've notice that if I receive a notification from the Stack Exchange Android app, when I go to open it, the notification menu doesn't display properly (*see pictures below*).

**Upon the app first opening:**

[image]

**After clicking the red notification box (Note how nothing is displayed. It's just a blank panel):**

[image]

Once I click out of the blank panel and re-click the on the notification symbol the menu displays properly. My question is:

**Is this a known issue and if so, are there any fixes for it?**

Comment: For what it's worth, it [used to be worse](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263459/clicking-on-a-notification-on-android-app-opens-an-empty-feed). (i.e. always open up blank.)

Comment: Could you mention the app version? This is to differentiate between beta user and not.

Comment: The app version is 1.0.77

Comment: This is fun. What phone / version of Android are you using? If you try 1.0.78 (only on the beta channel) does the same thing happen? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262151/open-beta-testing-of-the-stack-exchange-android-app